# Are smooth solutions to a PDE dense in the space of $L^2$ solutions to the PDE?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let's say I have a linear differential operator $P$ with smooth coefficients between bundles $E$ and $F$ over a smooth compact manifold $X$ with smooth boundary. Let's consider $P$ as an operator between the Sobolev spaces $P\colon L^2(X;E)\to L^2_{-m}(X;F)$, giving us a subspace $\ker P\subseteq L^2(X;E)$. Is $\ker P\cap C^\infty(X;E)$ dense in $\ker P$?

For example, we can consider $d\colon L^2(B^n;\bigwedge^*T^*B^n)\to L^2_{-1}(B^n;\bigwedge^*T^*B^n)$, in which case the question asks whether smooth closed forms on a ball are $L^2$-dense in $L^2$ closed forms on the ball.

I'm reasonably confident that the answer to the question is yes, at least with appropriate assumptions, but if you know of an analysis textbook that handles something like this situation, I'd appreciate a reference.